# Current amplitude of an Electrical Fast Transient

Tags: voltage, current, transient

I am trying to build my own EFT generator as close as I can to (IEC 610000-4-4). In order to achieve that I need to figure out the parameters of the waveforms that need to be produced. I am at a stage where I would need to figure out the current that my generator needs to deliver to a 50 ohms and a 1000 ohms load.

I am not quite sure how to determine that value. I imagine that the current will be a function of time, given that the voltage is also a function of time, but figuring out the peak amplitude is where I feel stuck now.

Since the current is not mentioned in the standard I figured the way to go about this is to start with the energy that is delivered by a single pulse and figure it out from there.

https://www.megccr.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/4_Transient_immunity_testing.pdf

[image]

I will be using the EFT - single pulse portion of the graph.
I deduced the following:

```
- 500V W=5*10^-5 Joules
- 1000V W=2*10^-4 Joules
- 2000V W=5*10^-4 Joules
- 4000V W=3*10^-3 Joules
```

The equation for energy is given by [image]

According to the standard IEC 61000-4-4 the waveform of a single pulse has a duration of approximately 300ns.
[image]

Can someone tell me if I am in the right path, am I missing something obvious.

Comment: Using a simulator seems like a good route to take.

Comment: I agree but I do not know of any simulator capable of simulating EFT pulses. Any ideas?

Comment: Micro-cap, LTspice. I use microcap.

Comment: oh cool, but do they have a built in EFT generator block that can be used? 
Also is Micro-cap free?

Comment: micro-cap is free at the moment. You make the fast transient voltage shape by looking into what the equivalent circuit is for the generator. I've done this successfully for 61000-4-5 surges. You don't need to precisely emulate it of course.

Comment: where can I find said equivalent circuit?

Comment: I googled it for the surge spec.

Comment: I spent like 3-4 hours looking and I cant seem to find anything…

Comment: Quick look: https://accelonix.nl/wp-content/uploads/IEC-61000-4-4-4-5-Burst_Surge-EMC-Workshop-juni-2019.pdf

Comment: I searched for images using: "61000-4-4 EFT generator circuit schematic"

Comment: I stubled on that too, but couldn’t really find an equivalent circuit to simulate

Comment: @Andyaka Is this a valid approach to find the current? P = E / t -> P = 0.0002 Joules / 300ns -> P = 666.67 W Now to find the current : P = V * I-> I = P / V-> I = 666.67/1000 -> I = 666mA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume a Thevenin source, peak current into a short is simply Ip = Vp / Zo.

The restriction on voltages into 1k and 50 ohm loads more or less stipulates this.

We could still do some tricks with reactance, or nonlinear circuits.  Roughly speaking, perhaps we use a series capacitor whose "reactance" at the switch's edge rate, to give this apparent V/I ratio; but the waveform will vary with load.  Or maybe we use diodes in some way, to direct pulse source(s) into the load, or clamp an otherwise-significant reversal.  Whatever the case, these will give a source impedance that's either reactive (depends on frequency --> waveform depends on load) or nonlinear (depends on voltage/current/load resistance).

A resistive source is best, being most flexible (least load-dependent).  The downside is it will most likely require a lot more power/energy than otherwise.  Trivial case: take the C-dependent example above, and put an attenuator after it: the attenuator gives as much load independence (isolation) as it does signal attenuation.

I would need to do some experiments to know for sure (read: I'd be happy to do it, for a price), but my guess is the waveform and amplitude tolerances are loose enough to get 50-80% of stored energy into the output.

---

Edit: your calculations suggest a square pulse, which is not a good approximation of an exponential waveform, not over the time period shown.  Put visually:

[image: pulse waveform]

The blue curve is a square wave of 300 ns.  Visually, it vastly exceeds the red curve at all points except the first few nanoseconds.

We can adjust the pulse time to better approximate properties of the curve.  If we want equal flux or charge (area under the curve, for voltage or current wave respectively), we can approximate the red curve as \$A e^{-t/\tau}\$, for \$\tau = (50 \,\textrm{ns}) / \ln 2\$.  (50 ns is the given half-life of the exponential decay, while the time constant is the 37%-point; \$\ln 2\$ is the conversion factor between these points.)  The integral is \$A \tau\$, so a square pulse of \$A\$ amplitude and \$\tau\$ duration (72.1 ns) will fit alright.

If we want energy instead of flux/charge, we need to take the square of the voltage/current first, instead.  Squaring an exponential simply halves the time constant, so the energy-equivalent square pulse is \$A^2\$ tall and \$\tau/2\$ (36 ns) wide.  (We also need energy into a load, so the \$A^2\$ is implicitly multiplied or divided by resistance (current or voltage respectively) to get power.)

Comment: I am sorry if I am not following what you said, but I reread 3-4 times what was written and genuinely did not understand anything...

Comment: Let's start at the top, do you know Thevenin's theorem?

Comment: yes I know Thevenin's theorem

Comment: Ok, then you understand the first two lines? Regarding the 3rd, consider an ideal voltage source of some pulse waveform, then put a R+C in series -- a complex source impedance, but Thevenin still applies. How does the waveform change between open, matched, and short-circuit cases?  Now change the ratio of R*C to pulse risetime: how does this affect the (open/match/short) results?  Add an attenuator after: how does this affect the results?

Comment: Okay so I sort of understand what you are saying, but how is that related to my question? How does that give me the current for 1 pulse?

Comment: Unless you're asking something different from what I understand: the current waveform is simply the voltage waveform scaled to Ip = Vp / Zo (into a short circuit, or any other value as given by the load resistance, by applying Thevenin's theorem)

Comment: I understand, I was just confused by why were we discussing the attenuator and also, i am not necessarly looking to find the precise waveform, i am ok with simply the amplitude.

Comment: Is this a valid approach to find the current? P = E / t -> P = 0.0002 Joules / 300ns -> P = 666.67 W Now to find the current : P = V * I-> I = P / V-> I = 666.67/1000 -> I = 666mA

Comment: P = E/t works for the average value, or a square pulse. Why is your V/I ratio wrong though? Into what load condition would you measure this?

Comment: I agree with you that it is valid for a square pulse, but it is a fair approximation i believe.

The load I am thinking is 50ohms?

Comment: @DimitarZhekov See edit; proof of the relations given has been left as exercise for the reader.